# Add a layer to a list following names

Tags: r, purrr

I have this one layer list :

```
have <- list("a" = 1, "b.a" = 2, "b.b" = 3)
```

I need this 2 layers list :

```
need <- list("a" = 1, "b" = list("a" = 2, "b" = 3))
```

Would be even better if the solution could be recursive. The goal is to structurate the data as it could be parsed to some Json file for example.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recursive function should do the trick:

```r
f <- function(obj) {
  nms <- lapply(strsplit(names(obj), '\\.'), function(x){
    if(length(x) == 1) x else c(x[1], paste(x[-1], collapse = '.'))
  })
  first_nms <- sapply(nms, `[`, 1)
  last_nms <- sapply(nms, `[`, -1)
  un_nms <- unique(first_nms)
  setNames(lapply(un_nms, function(x) {
    o <- unname(obj[first_nms %in% x])
    if(length(o) == 1) unlist(o) else
      f(setNames(o, last_nms[first_nms %in% x]))
    }), un_nms)
}
```

Testing, we have:

```r
have <- list("a" = 1, "b.a" = 2, "b.b" = 3)

f(have)
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$a
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $b$b
#> [1] 3
```

And we can see it works on deeply nested lists:

```r
f(list(a = 1, b.a = 2, b.b = 3, c.a.a = 4, c.a.b = 5, c.b.a = 6, c.b.b = 7))
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$a
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $b$b
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> 
#> $c
#> $c$a
#> $c$a$a
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $c$a$b
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> 
#> $c$b
#> $c$b$a
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $c$b$b
#> [1] 7
```

Comment: I like that solution. I guess there's not a simpler one. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using `rrapply()` (package `rrapply`). First, we melt the list to a data.frame with `rrapply(how = "melt")`, then split the names into individual columns, and finally convert the data.frame back to a nested list with `rrapply(how = "unmelt")`:

```
library(rrapply)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

have <- list("a" = 1, "b.a" = 2, "b.b" = 3)

## tidyverse 
need_tidy <- rrapply(have, how = "melt") |>
  separate_wider_delim(L1, delim = ".", names_sep = "_", too_few = "align_start") |>
  rrapply(how = "unmelt")

str(need_tidy)
#> List of 2
#>  $ a: num 1
#>  $ b:List of 2
#>   ..$ a: num 2
#>   ..$ b: num 3

## data.table
need_dt <- as.data.table(rrapply(have, how = "melt"))
need_dt <- cbind(need_dt[, tstrsplit(L1, split = "\\.")], need_dt[, "value"])
need_dt <- rrapply(need_dt, how = "unmelt")

str(need_dt)
#> List of 2
#>  $ a: num 1
#>  $ b:List of 2
#>   ..$ a: num 2
#>   ..$ b: num 3
```

The same code also works to construct more deeply nested lists:

```
## deeply nested list
have <- list("a" = 1, "b.a.x.y.z" = 2, "b.b" = 3)

need_tidy <- rrapply(have, how = "melt") |>
  separate_wider_delim(L1, delim = ".", names_sep = "_", too_few = "align_start") |>
  rrapply(how = "unmelt")

str(need_tidy)
#> List of 2
#>  $ a: num 1
#>  $ b:List of 2
#>   ..$ a:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ x:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ y:List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ z: num 2
#>   ..$ b: num 3
```

Comment: This is cool! Now I know there is a package can do it, cheers!